# Snippets not working? [HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure]

Tags: support, bug, browser-support

I'm getting a `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure` when I try to run any snippets on Stack Overflow. I'm using Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 19.10 (although this is a 500 error, so I'm guessing it's not my fault).

Update: Also tested on Chrome on the same PC, and Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit) on another Ubuntu 19.10 machine (same network) with the same results.

[image]

To replicate (if it's not just me) click "Run code snippet" below.

```js
console.log("test");
```

Is anyone else experiencing the same, and does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Have you tried using a different device or browser?

Comment: I get the same result whether I'm running it on Chrome or Firefox and whether logged in or not.

Comment: But have you tried a different device?

Comment: It's working for you, and you're on a different device.

Comment: @Joundill The point of *you* doing it on another device is to check if it's a device issue or network issue. Someone else testing on another device isn't helpful for testing your device or network.

Comment: I can confirm that I also get the same error on Firefox, Chrome & Edge on Win10.

Comment: @LemmyX Just gave it a go on a different device, another Ubuntu 19.10 machine running FF 76.0.1 (64-bit). Same error message

Comment: Then it's most likely your network

Comment: @LemmyX Except AlphaD can repro (I personally can't)

Comment: I can't repro on Firefox 76.0.1 on Win10.

Comment: It just happened for me, Linux using Brave (Chrome-like). Since it's a server error message, it's not going to be a network issue (between Joundill and SE's servers, anyway). Clearly an intermittent server failure.

Comment: Same issue, Win 10, latest Chrome.

Comment: I've been getting it consistently since at least this morning (8pm here at the moment). I haven't noticed a single snippet running correctly

Comment: @Joundill If the server is broken (and likely it is), then no snippets will work...

Comment: @FZs LemmyX, Nick and rene aren't experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I don't know what could go on the server... Our best chance is to wait for someone in the staff, until then, use https://codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Joundill - There's probably more than one server. Perhaps there's a regional component to what server you try to connect to, or just a random component. It's a server error, there's no need for anyone other than SE staff to do further work diagnosing it.

Comment: I believe the HA-proxy config of SE prefers to send you to the same server from the available pool so once you've hit a bad one and that server isn't taken out of rotation you'll be able to repro. Those users that don't experience the issue got a different server assigned. If region matters (I don't think it does) I'm in western europe, probably routing through AMS-IX.

Comment: Can reproduce, in California, if region matters.

Comment: having this for the last 5h at least. Not cool at all -.-

Comment: Region may really matter... It doesn't work for me (Hungary, Central Europe); but when I use VPN with different locations, it works somewhere.

Comment: If it is region dependent, those regions must be small. Snippets are broken on my home network but work fine on my server ~50 miles away.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Winamp?

Comment: i get the same error with edge.

Comment: Same thing happens for me in safari, so this is definitely affecting a variety of people and browsers. Another thing: this isn't just happening on Stack Overflow, snippets on Code Review are doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: actually it works again.

Comment: Concur with @Nina, it was broken for a couple days, but now it looks to be functioning again.

Comment: Now works for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be resolved.

Only affected certain users, see comments on question for details.

Comment: I have this issue now in Chrome 84 Win 10

Comment: Me too, also in FF

Comment: I'm also having this issue on Chrome v85 and Firefox Dev v79 on Win 10. **Edit: It seems to be working now.**